# What csplit-like command lets me create several files from one text file?

Tags: shell, text, awk, csplit

Are there any tools to do what I want already?  I'd like to split the file 'one' at lines starting with @, followed by a filename:

```
$ cat one
@header
-- header --
@body
-- body --
@body isn't a split point
@footer
-- footer --

$ splitit one
$ ls
body footer header one 
$ cat header
-- header --
$ cat body
-- body --
@body isn't a split point
$ cat footer
-- footer --
```

What is splitit?

Use case:

- edit my html, js, css and docs in the one file (the files aren't large)
- m4 preprocesses the one file
- splitit reads m4 output and writes out several files
- indent/beautify the files
- recombine into fewer files with cat...

Comment: Are you telling us you want to create a tool named `splitit` with that functionality or advertising one that you have created? If the former - how can we help you create a tool to beautify a files contents when we don't know what that content is other than a line like `-- header --`?

Comment: @EdMorton actually, I did write a tool to do this in c a few years ago, but I'm sure it can be done in awk pretty easily - I'm not an awk expert.  I don't need a beautifier - those exist.  Just need splitit.

Comment: Then get rid of all the requirements that don't apply and just list what you need help with so no-one wastes their time trying to do something else.. Also include what you've tried so far. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NF==1 && sub(/^@/,""){f=$0; next} {print > f}' one
```

If you will have many output files and don't use GNU awk then you'll have to close them as you go:

```
awk 'NF==1 && sub(/^@/,""){close(f); f=$0; next} {print > f}' one
```

Comment: $ awk -F'[@[:space:]]' 'NF==2{f=$2; next} {print > f}' one
    awk: cannot open "" for output (No such file or directory)

Comment: Then your input file doesn't look like the one you posted. Run it against the input file you posted and it will work. I modified the command btw - use the updated version but that's unrelated to the error you got.

Comment: Thank you, your splitit worked (I tried the first one).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative *awk* approach:

```
awk -F' *|@' '$0~/^@/ && NF==2{fn=$2;next}{ print > fn }' one
```

- `-F' *|@'` - compound field separator (space(s) or `@`)

Comment: @JackAndrews, of course, line `@body isn't a split point` have spaces and therefore, `NR` (total number of fields) would be greater than `2`

Comment: `printf '@file\nA Background\n...\n' |awk -F' *|@' 'NF==2{fn=$2;next}{ print > fn }'`
creates one file called 'Background'

Comment: checks and passes